# TO: field shifted on Email from UIActivityViewController on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've reviewed a bunch of posts and figured someone must have experienced this.  I'm seeing some weird UI shifting on the TO:, Cc:, and Bcc: fields with the email coming from the UIActivityViewController. I think it's an iOS 7 issue.  I was not able to reproduce this in iOS 6.  I'd post a picture if I could, never posted here so I'm unable to share a screenshot.   If the user selects the TO:, Cc:, or Bcc: field, the blue cursor is slightly above these field rather than centered.  When the user starts typing the bottom line shifts to the bottom of the cursor and covers most of the "TO:" text.   When users click out of one of these fields after typing an email, the newly typed text slightly shift down and centers to the "TO:".  Slightly odd user experience.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure all interaction with that class is done on the main thread - creation, messaging. Anything done on other threads (dispatch queues) can create weird stuff. Also that you maintain a strong reference to the MF... class until you have completely finished with using it.

Comment: You can share an image either by uploading it from your local computer or uploading it onto the web (with the http://imgur.com/ service for example) and clicking the Image button (then selecting the relevant option). Don't hesitate to edit your question.